# OData Source to SQL Server 2012 Issue in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, odata

Hoping someone can help out with this one. I'm putting together a SSIS package in Visual Studio 2015 which is using OData as the source and SQL Server 2012 as the destination.

The authentication for OData should be set to basic. I'm getting the following error in the OData Source when I'm setting the Project Target Server version to SQL Server 2012. However if I use another DB I have access to as the database with SQL Server 2016 the connection succeeds without issue.

The difference I can see in the connection manager for OData is when the target server version is set to SQL Server 2016, I get an additional option in the connection manager which is an authentication dropdown and it lets me set the account type to Basic. I don't get this option in the OData connection manager when target server version is set to SQL Server 2012.

I've also downloaded an OData Source for SQL Server 2012 extension from Microsoft site but this has had no effect.

Has anyone experienced and resolved this issue before?

[image]

[image]